# PHPStorm not finding images on build, how to configure?

Tags: css, phpstorm

I'm new to PHPStorm and already ran into a problem which kills my will to use the IDE:

I write paths to images in css like

> background-image: url(/CSS/Img/separator.png);

That is the correct path that the IDE will accept without throwing an error.

Then I run the website and get the error

> GET localhost:63342/CSS/Img/separator.png 404 (Not Found)

That's understandable, because the file is at

> localhost:63342/ProjectName/CSS/Img/separator.png

So I'm guessing I need to configure something. I tried to google for a solution, but I honestly don't even know what to search for.

Comment: I suggest to use proper / full featured web server (Apache/nginx/IIS/whatever) instead of **simple** built-in server as it requires to have this extra bit in the path to have it working. Sure -- you could use `css/img/separator.png` (notice the absence of leading slash) but it's not that of a great idea (may work in some situations and may be broken in other) .. although worth trying.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that as soon as I get home. I already have xampp installed with Apache running. Would you be so kind and provide some more info on how to configure PHPStorm to use Apache?

Comment: Only this link: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Configuring+PHP+Environment

Comment: Thanks, I followed everything on that page but my problem is still the same :(

Comment: What do you mean? If you specify your own server then built in will not be used.

Comment: Well: I right click my html site and select "Run"....the site loads but he still doesn't find the images

Comment: So .. does it uses your XAMPP server .. or is it still served by built-in one?

Comment: I added the XAMPP Apache to the deployment settings and made it standard, but when I click the "Run" button it still wants me to choose one of the other options.

Comment: Sorry, but I need to see screenshots (deployment entry; your "run" config etc) to advise anything further

Comment: Alright, here are 3 screens: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/991x695q90/673/XB0p5J.png https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/991x695q90/537/IQS2VU.png https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1092x702q90/673/r09ox7.png

Comment: Well .. your URL in 3rd screenshot still has reference to built-in server. Change it to use proper one instead.

Comment: On related note: it could be related to this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I finally made it work!

Many thanks to [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone) for getting me on the right path and providing me with this useful link on [how to configure PHPStorm with XAMPP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE)!

This was a step in the right direction, but not everything I needed to get it to work.
The main fault is of course with me, because I am new to this IDE and didn't know my way around. Finally, to get it working I had to do two more steps:

1. Make a new run-configuration for PHP with built-in Webserver.
2. Upload my project to the server root, which is
   "D:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT_NAME" in my case

(I'd post links for the other steps, but I don't have enough reputation here)

Then when you hit "Run", it just opens the debug window and does nothing. This is where you'd expect the IDE to open up a browser for you, but you gotta do it yourself and input the right path.
In my case it is now "localhost:80/index.php".
It's a bit weird, but at least it works now! :)

Comment: You must be doing something wrong then ... 2 more videos to watch: **1)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/webinar-recording-deployment-with-phpstorm/ **2)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add in ProjectName to the path?

```
background-image: url( ProjectName/CSS/Img/separator.png);
```

Alternatively, you can walk up and down the directory. Sometimes confusing as it is natural next step on your HD, but the web server (locahost) is using relative path so it doesn't know how to get from where it is to where the png file is so you need to be explicit or walk it down or up from "your are here" that the web server is telling you.

one step back

```
../
```

two (etc)

```
../../
```

You can use this approach to navigate to root or other level then walk the tree again

example,

```
background-image: url(../ProjectName/Img/separator.png);
```

which says step down a directory level "../" from wherever you are then use the following directory structure "ProjectName/Img/separator.png" from that point.

or

```
background-image: url(../../ProjectName/Img/separator.png);
```

which says step 2 directories down and then ..

hope that helps

Comment: *"Why not just add in ProjectName to the path?"* Because it's a wrong approach -- to hard code dev mode only paths.

Comment: Lazy 100% agreed, but I was answering the question versus educating on the right method. I don't and wouldn't code with absolute paths, but nothing worse than answering someones question with a new concept they might not understand.